# Storing the results of double for loop in a vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have an example code for a double for loop.  I am having trouble understanding how 
**Candles<-c(Candles,c)** is storing the results of c<-c+n in a vector. Isn't it concatenating Candles and c.  Thank you for explanation.

```
Name<-c("A","B","C","D","E",
    "F","G","H","I","J",
    "K","L","M")
Age<-c(15,14,21,24,74,
   15,3,37,19,39,
   17,2,7)

jjj<-data.frame(Name,Age)

Candles<-c()
  for(Age in jjj$Age){
    c<-0
     for (n in 0:Age){
       c<-c+n
   }
 Candles<-c(Candles,c)
}
```

Candles

Comment: This doesn't answer your "why" question, but double `for` loops are rarely needed in R, especially when you are starting with a data frame. This looks like you are building a variable that could be defined in one line as the sum of the series: `Candles = (jjj$age)*(jjj$age+1)/2` Or something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a short sentence, `Candles <- c(Candles, c)` can be understood as `Candels.append(c)` in Python in this case.

It is not overwriting the variable `Candles` in a way, that the new `Candles` will contain two elements, and the first element is the old `Candle` the the second element is the `c`.

For more information about function `c`, try:

```
?"c"
```

I found the details very helpful:

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression. Pairlists are treated as lists, but non-vector components (such names and calls) are treated as one-element lists which cannot be unlisted even if recursive = TRUE.
>
> c is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names, for example to turn an array into a vector. as.vector is a more intuitive way to do this, but also drops names. Note too that methods other than the default are not required to do this (and they will almost certainly preserve a class attribute).

Comment: B.Mr.W, Thanks for the answer.  I am still trying to understand the text above.